# django/innodb -- problem with old sessions and transactions

Tags: mysql, django, innodb, celery

We just switched our MySQL database from MyIsam to Innodb, and we are seeing an odd issue arise in Django. Whenever we make a database transaction, the existing sessions do not pick it up...ever. We can see the new record in the database from a mysql terminal, but the existing django sessions (ie a shell that was already open), would not register the change. For example:

Shell 1:

```
>>> my_obj = MyObj.objects.create(foo="bar")
>>> my_obj.pk
1
```

Shell 2 (was open before the above)

```
>>> my_obj = MyObj.objects.filter(pk=1)
[]
```

Shell 3 (MySQL):

```
mysql> select id from myapp_my_obj where id = 1;
id
1
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

EDIT: To clarify, Shell 2 was opened before Shell 1, then I make the create Shell 1, then I try to view the object that I created in Shell 2.

EDIT2: The big picture is that I have a celery task that is being passed the primary key from the object that is created. When I was using MyISAM, it found it every time, and now it throws `ObjectDoesNotExist`, even though I can see that the object is created in the database.

Comment: So, just to be clear, this behavior worked fine when you were using MyIsam and stopped working when you switched to Innodb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `create()` command commits the transaction for the current shell, but doesn't do anything to the transaction in the second shell.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/

Your second thread that can't see what's done in the first because it is in a transaction of its own. Transactions isolate the database so that when a transaction is committed, everything happens at a single point in time, including select statements. This is the `A` in [`ACID`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). Try running

```
from django.db import transaction; transaction.commit()
```

in the second shell. That should commit the current transaction and start a new one. You can also use `transaction.rollback()` to acheive the same thing if you haven't modified anything in the db in the current shell.

Edit Edit:

You may need to grab your specific db connection to make this work. Try this:

```
import django.db
django.db.connection._commit()
```

More information about this problem here:

http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/msg/55fa3724d2754013

The relevant bit is:

```
If you want script1.py (using an InnoDB table) to see committed updates from 
other transactions you can change the transaction isolation level like so: 

from django.db import connection 
connection.cursor().execute('set transaction isolation level read 
committed') 

Alternatively you can enable the database's version of auto-commit, which 
"commits" queries as well as updates, so that each new query by script1 will 
be in its own transaction: 

connection.cursor().execute('set autocommit=1') 
Either one allows script1 to see script2's updates.
```

**So, the tl;dr is that you need to set your InnoDB transaction isolation to `READ-COMMITTED`.**

Comment: Then why can I see it in the database? It seems like it is committing, but the thread that the open shell is running on is not picking it up?

Comment: Yes, but I am issuing a new query -- a select -- shouldn't that ignore the transaction?

Comment: No, all your interactions with the database will be in that same transaction until you leave it and start a new one. That's the point - everything that happens within the transaction deals with the database as if it's frozen in time.

Comment: So how could I start a new transaction in that existing shell?

Comment: `from django.db import transaction; transaction.commit()`

Comment: That will commit the current transaction and _should_ start a new one.

Comment: if you haven't changed data, you can also issue a `rollback()` command, which is slightly easier on the database (but obviously this doesn't matter when you're just testing).

Comment: I have not issued a query in the other shell, so I cannot commit anything. I am just doing a select in the other shell. I get `TransactionManagementError: This code isn't under transaction management`

Comment: The transaction starts when you start the shell. Does the `commit()` explicitly fail? What about the `rollback()`?

Comment: Sorry -- I edited my comment above -- yes, it explicitly fails

Comment: Hmmm. I think your problem is still likely related to transactions - that's the main advantage of Innodb after all - but I'm not sure why the commit or rollback don't work.

Comment: Also try `import django.db; django.db.connection._commit() `

Comment: That worked, but it is going to be very cumbersome to put that into all of our celery tasks that operate asynchronously. Is there a global django setting to ensure that this happens before all _non_-data altering queries?

Comment: Look at my edited answer. You need to modify the transaction level (which you can do at a database conf level if you need to).

Comment: update your my.cnf to set your `transaction_isolation` to `READ-COMMITTED` to fix it globally.